# User Input with predefined variable - batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, user-input

I'm trying to make a script in batch where the user will input their name and then have to input it again. However, I want the user to be able to type in, "my name is [name]" and have that be considered "correct" as well.

Currently my code is not recognizing the %name% variable when there is user input before it and instead goes to the :incorrect label.

Code:

```
@ CLS
@ set /P name="Type your name: "
@ set /P userinput="Type your name again: "
@ if /I "userinput"=="%name%" goto correct
@ if /I "userinput"=="my name is %name%" goto correct
@ goto :incorrect
@ :correct
@ CLS & echo Correct! & pause
@ :incorrect
@ CLS & echo Incorrect! & pause
```

However, I wouldn't mind it considering it "correct" as long as the user types their name *somewhere* within their input, therefore I think it would need to somehow parse<sup>?</sup> the input to find if the variable %name% exists within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't wrap `userinput` in %% when testing it in your if statements, so the program interprets it as plain text instead of a variable. Try:

```
@ CLS
@ set /P name="Type your name: "
@ set /P userinput="Type your name again: "
@ if /I "%userinput%"=="%name%" goto correct
@ if /I "%userinput%"=="my name is %name%" goto correct
@ goto :incorrect
@ :correct
@ CLS & echo Correct! & pause
@ :incorrect
@ CLS & echo Incorrect! & pause
```